# Spark streaming: HBase connection is closed when use hbaseMapPartitions

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, hbase

in my Spark streaming application i use a HBaseContext to put some values into HBase, one put operation for each processed message.

If i use hbaseForeachPartitions, everything is ok.

```
 dStream
  .hbaseForeachPartition(
    hbaseContext,
    (iterator, connection) => {
      val table = connection.getTable("namespace:table")
      // putHBase is external function in the same Scala object
      val results = iterator.flatMap(packet => putHBaseAndOther(packet))
      table.close()
      results
    }
 )
```

Instead with hbaseMapPartitions the connection to HBase is closed.

```
 dStream
  .hbaseMapPartition(
    hbaseContext,
    (iterator, connection) => {
      val table = connection.getTable("namespace:table")
      // putHBase is external function in the same Scala object
      val results = iterator.flatMap(packet => putHBaseAndOther(packet))
      table.close()
      results
    }
 )
```

Someone can explain me why?